# Dynamically declaring and instantiating objects based on a parameter

Tags: vb.net, declaration, instantiation

Is it possible to dynamically declare and instantiate objects based on a parameter in VB.net?

It seems crazy that I would have to declare every single object i wish to instantiate.

The code below doesn't work, but maybe there is some kind of workaround to achieve the same result?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim jeff As String = "Jeff"
        DynamicDeclare(jeff)
    End Sub


    Private Sub DynamicDeclare(ByVal objectName As String)
        Dim objectName As New Person
    End Sub
End Class

Class Person
    Property FirstName As String
    Property Age As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: what is that you are trying to do exactly ?

Comment: And how excactly would you reference a non existing object in code before "Denamicly Declaring" it?

Comment: Well this is just a mockup of the problem, but I have a form class and I would like it to be declared and instantiated by sending the results of a select case statement. These parameters contain all the information to for each form -- the form name (for slight modifications to the UI) and data, also for the UI

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection, something like this may work for your needs. I haven't tested it, but it should work.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim jeff As String = "Jeff"
        Dim methodName as string = "DynamicDeclare"
        Dim type as Type = GetType(Person)
        Dim method as System.Reflection.MethodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName)
        Dim person as Person = method.Invoke(Nothing, new object(){jeff})
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Person
   Property FirstName As String
   Property Age As Integer

    Public Function DynamicDeclare(ByVal objectName As String) as Person
       Dim person As New Person
       person.FirstName = objectName
       Return person
    End Function
End Class
```